# Sony SmartWatch - How to know if LED is supported by an accessory device?

Tags: android, sony-smartwatch

Which API can tell me the information about if LED is supported by a specific accessory device?

Comment: Can you elaborate any?It is really hard to tell what you are asking.

Comment: Yes you've tagged this with Smartwatch but you don't mention anything about the Smartwatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the SmartWatch nor the Smart Wireless Headset Pro contains a LED.

However, you can use the Capabilities API to get information about the device capabilities, as described in chapter 4 in the [SDK](http://developer.sonymobile.com/wportal/devworld/technology/smart-extras/smart-extension-sdk).

The URI for the content provider of the LED is defined in the utility classes, as well as an URI for the content provider of the Capabilities view.

```
Registration$Capabilities
Registration$Led
Registration$LedColumns
```