# startLedPattern in ControlExtension Sony SmartWatch

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

Im doing a call in my Control extends ControlExtension class:

```
startLedPattern(0, Color.RED, 0010, 0010, 3);
```

My SmartWatch does not blink, Im not sure what the first parameter is? And what value should it have?

Update:
Looks like it is not possible:
[Sony SmartWatch - How to know if LED is supported by an accessory device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007048/sony-smartwatch-how-to-know-if-led-is-supported-by-an-accessory-device)

Why does this call exists then, is for the LED in the phone? Any sample source code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SmartExtension SDK was first developed for the SmartWatch and Smart Wireless Headset pro, but was also intended to be used for future products. Thus, we took a broad perspective on the API and its methods, to be able to be as future proof as possible.

So regarding the LED, as you say, it does not exist on the SmartWatch and the code is not there for the LED on the phone either, but could be used for any future products that might come in the future.